# Agenda View - Display entire time range

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using agendaWeek and agendaDay views.  These views are displaying the entire 24 hour block (with half hour increments).  Because all 24 hours are being displayed, vertical scrolling is enabled.  Is it possible to scale the time increments enough to prevent vertical scrolling?

I am guessing that this will require a lot of CSS manipulation, but I am hoping not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked *"Is it possible to scale the time increments enough to prevent vertical scrolling?"* Technically the answer to this is no, because you have no control over the height of the user's viewport. In other words, you can't predict the size of the end user's screen. The could decide to view the site in a window with a height of 20px, if they really wanted to. Unlikely, but theoretically possible.

However, there are realistic assumptions you can make, about what users are likely to do, and what you are prepared to support. And you do have some tools in fullCalendar to help you, as well. If you made a more thorough study of the documentation, you may have found the following:

1) You can set a fixed pixel height for the whole calendar using the `height` option. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/height/

2) You can set a fixed pixel height for the view area of the calendar using the `contentHeight` option. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/contentHeight/

3) You can set the `slotDuration` option to control what time period each block covers. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotDuration/

4) You can also use minTime (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/minTime/) and maxTime (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/maxTime/) options to start/end the view at different times, if that works for you. e.g. you could have it start at 9am and finish at 5pm, if that was appropriate, thus reducing the amount of vertical space used.

Comment: All these options do is control the height of the rendered calendar.  I am currently doing that, but there is no way to force all 24 hours to render, without scrolling inside a fixed height calendar.

My calendar is set to 700px height, yet the content, minTime = 0, maxTime = 24, will still scroll because each slot is too tall.  There does not appear to be a way to control the height of each slot.

Comment: ah ok, you mean you want to prevent scrolling of the view _within the calendar_, not prevent scrolling of the whole browser window? Ok. The question was not clear on that point. Setting `height: 1180` is enough to prevent that, but not many people have a screen tall enough (once you account for browser UI, padding etc), so then you end up with scrolling of the browser window instead.

Comment: Setting `aspectRatio: 0.8` will also achieve the same effect, but again generally at the cost of scrolling the browser window instead.

Comment: The next option is to change `slotDuration` as I suggested above. If you set `slotDuration: "01:00"` (i.e. 1-hour slots) it will fit a whole day comfortably in a height of 700px. The minimum workable time to fit in that height seems to be "00:50", but that's a rather odd duration and might be confusing to users. An hour is probably neater.

Comment: The last option, which is not official supported, but perfectly straightforward, is simply to override the default CSS. There is a rule `.fc-time-grid .fc-slats td {
    height: 1.5em;
    border-bottom: 0;
}` which controls it. You could reduce the height to whatever you require. `0.4em` will just about fit it into a 700px height, but you might find you also want to alter the slotDuration to show fewer slots, otherwise they start to overlap and look messy.

Comment: Personally I think the slotDuration option is the simplest and best. If you note, I suggested it in the answer, but you didn't say whether you'd tried it or not.

Comment: Thanks so much for this.  I ended up using a combo of slotDuration and aspectRatio.  Had to work with the client to ensure I met their needs.